# Server doesn't connect to port 443

Tags: networking, server

My server is not connecting to port 443.

as you can see:

**HTTPS:**

```
root@lb03:/usr/local/bin# wget https://google.com/example.html
--2023-11-01 16:00:04--  https://google.com/example.html
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 172.217.16.238, 2a00:1450:4009:815::200e
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|172.217.16.238|:443...
```

**HTTP:**

```
root@lb03:/usr/local/bin# wget http://google.com/example.html
--2023-11-01 16:00:22--  http://google.com/example.html
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 172.217.16.238, 2a00:1450:4009:815::200e
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|172.217.16.238|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2023-11-01 16:00:22 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

and this is happening with all websites, i just used google as an example.

Comment: You don't have any kind of proxy or VPN or anything intercepting your traffic in the network you're connected to, do you?

Comment: I don't think so, at least not on the server, i don't know if on the ISP has.